# How to align y labels when using 'add_axes'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, alignment, yaxis

I have created a plot with some data points (in blue), a fit (in purple) and I have managed to include the fit residuals (fit-datapoints) by using 'add_axes' as shown below:

```
#Plot and fit:
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
frame1 = fig1.add_axes((.1,.3,.8,.6))
plt.scatter(a/nshots,m/nshots,zorder=-1,s=1)
plt.plot(a/nshots,fit(a/nshots),color='purple')
plt.xlabel(r'$a_i/N_s$ (mV)')
plt.ylabel(r'$m_i/N_s$ (count/$N_s$)')
plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',direction='in',right=True,top=True)
#Residuals:
frame2=fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.8,.2))
plt.scatter(a/nshots,m/nshots-fit(a/nshots),zorder=-1,s=1,color='pink')
plt.xlabel(r'$a_i/N_s$ (mV)')
plt.ylabel(r'residuals')
plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',direction='in',right=True,top=True)
```

However, I cannot seem to align the y labels on the resulting figure:

[image]

I have tried using things like plt.gca().yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1,0.1) and plt.gca().yaxis.labelpad=20 but I would very much prefer an approach where alignment is automated and I need not align the labels by hand.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you try fig.align_ylabels? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pyplots/align_ylabels.html

Comment: Thank you:) If you look at the linked image, you will see that the two y-labels 'residuals' and '$m_i/N_s$' are misaligned horizontally due to the y-ticks of the residuals plot showing two decimals.

Comment: Yes, I did try "fig1.align_ylabels()" and unfortunately I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'get_subplotspec'" :(

Comment: Yes, well don’t use `add_axes` and this will work fine.  If you want the axes to have different heights, use the `gridspec_kw={‘height_ratios’:[1, 0.3]})` argument to subplots.